# Story about a woman who crashes her ship and finds out she became emperor but she stays to have a wake

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Short Sci Fi story of a woman who crashes somewhere on earth I think Scotland or Ireland and when she asks to use the phone finds out that her friend the emperor has died and now she is the emperor. But she remains with the family for a wake.I think she was some sort of ranger and when they come to pick her up she does not forget the family and sends them a tractor, she also give one of the children an appointment to a military academy. I remember that the old man of the house called her "lass". I think the emperor lives in Antarctica but I can be mistaken. It is a relatively short story.

---

*Comment by OP reads:*

> I read it in The past few years and on its own not part of a collection or magazine. But it could have been fairly old by then. Some other details that I remember, she was a ranger of se sort and afterwards she helped the family she had the wake at with a tractor and for one son an appointment to a military academy.

Comment: Do you have an approximate year you read this? Was it in a magazine, a collection? Any other details that you can remember?

Comment: I read it in The past few years and on its own not part of a collection or magazine. But it could have been fairly old by then. Some other details that I remember, she was a ranger of se sort and afterwards she helped the family she had the wake at with a tractor and for one son an appointment to a military academy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it! It is called "New Years Wake" by Ann Wilson. It can be read on [project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/25746/25746-h/25746-h.htm).